# How does Windows know exactly when a power outage occurs?

Tags: windows, power

*(repost from [my stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65819963/how-does-windows-know-exactly-when-a-power-outage-occurs) which does not meet stackoverflow guidelines)*

After a power outage, I decided to check Event Viewer and saw that there was a critical "error" (it's obviously not an error, just a power outage) because of the power outage. I know how Windows could detect if there is an abnormal shutdown, but how does Windows know exactly when a power outage occurs and saves that information redundantly so quickly?

I know there is a small battery on my computer to keep the clock state, but I doubt it can output enough amperage to power a hard drive, RAM, and the CPU.

Comment: What is the event ID number?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Windows *doesnt* know exactly when the power goes out.  It is not possible to write to the disk.  However, it *does* know the last time it certain events were performed, as it logs them.  When power is returned, it sees there was a boot process, it sees there was not a proper shutdown, and based on its logs, it can give an approximate time the power went out.